# XM 10.1.0 & 10.1.1 + JSS & SXA - Could not load file or assembly 'Sitecore.Analytics, Version=16.0.0.0'

Tags: sxa, jss

`Vanilla Sitecore 10.1+` install with `JSS 16` and `SXA 10.1` installed.  After the initial install, I'm able to navigate to the Launchpad normally.  After a period of time or unknown trigger, I'm unable to navigate to the Launchpad, receiving this YSOD:

[image]

I've searched through my config files to see if there are any pipeline references to `Sitecore.Analytics`.  Most references are `patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines...` attributes for the following SXA processors:

- `Sitecore.XA.Feature.ErrorHandling.Pipelines.HtpRequestProcessed.SetStatusCode`
- `Sitecore.XA.Feature.Security.Pipelines.HttpRequestProcessed.RemoveServerInformationHeader`
- `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Theming.Pipelines.HtpRequestProcessed.FixInternetExplorerCompatibilityHeaders`
- `Sitecore.LayoutService.Analytics.Pipelines.InitializeTracker.SetUrlFromRouteData`
- `Sitecore.LayoutService.Analytics.Pipelines.MvcRequestBegin.DetermineTrackerEnabled`
- `Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Hosting.Mvc.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.DisableGraphQLRequestTracking`

Nothing really sticks out to me, but given the ease at which I'm able to reproduce this, I'm hoping others have already isolated the problem, found a resolution or have ideas on how to troubleshoot better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After analyzing the stack trace, I was able to isolate the culprit within the `Sitecore.LayoutService.Analytics.config` file.  There is a processor named: `Sitecore.LayoutService.Analytics.Pipelines.MvcRequestBegin.DetermineTrackerEnabled` that is explicitly referencing the Tracker.  Since I am using the XM topology, the Tracker dependency is not available and thus the exception is thrown.  I am able to get around this issue by adding this patch file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <mvc.requestBegin>
        <processor type="Sitecore.LayoutService.Analytics.Pipelines.MvcRequestBegin.DetermineTrackerEnabled, Sitecore.LayoutService.Analytics">
                <patch:delete />
        </processor>
      </mvc.requestBegin>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't explain the cause of the problem.  I looked through the *.scwdp files for Headless services and was unable to find an example where the `Sitecore.LayoutService.Analytics.config` was included within the App_Config directory.  I also was not able to reproduce this same issue in my DEV environment which was provisioned using ARM templates.

I installed Headless services on my local using a Sitecore package.  When I looked in my App_Data/packages directory, I noticed that I used the XP package (`Sitecore Headless Services Server for Sitecore 10.1.0 XP 16.0.0 rev. 210223.zip`) instead of XM.

You'll save yourself plenty of headaches if you make sure to use the correct package/wdp/container image if you're adding Headless Services to Sitecore.

Answer (score 3):

The following node needs to be added to the appsettings in web.config as part of the scaled install on CD

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="sxaxm:define" value="sxaxmonly"/>
</appSettings>
```

Reference Installation Guide

[image]